# R.id.controlid is not working

Tags: android, controls

I've added a new xml file to my android project under the path res/layout and I tried to call it from a source file :

```
View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewlayout, parent, false);
```

but it generated an error, and the control ID wasn't in the R.id list and I added a new control to the activity_main.xml and I had the same error R.id didn't recognize the TextView I add ( although I precised its ID and I  saved the file to update the R class before using R.id) but the error remained!

Comment: what error u facing dear...

Comment: Just try to build your project so the R class will be updated .. or just set your eclipse to build automatically.

Comment: Can please post your full XML layout as well as your logcat for this error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your IDE imported `android.R` and not the package of your application (`R` is located in your root package and must be imported if you reference it in a subpackage).

So if your imports contain

```
import android.R;
```

replace it by

```
import your.root.package.R;
```

Comment: actually no it's not importing it

Answer (score 0):

If  “R.id.xxx” is not solved Clean your project and then build it again , if the R cannot be resolved then

```
$ cd $ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
```

If the error remains check under the folder gen if R.java si generated, if not it means that you have an error in one of the xml files under res/layout